# Website links are not indexing on Google

Tags: google-search-console

I submitted sitemap in Google Console. It's giving me waning after crawling the page.

[image]

But I also tested in Robots.txt Tester for the inner page, it is showing the allowed message. My website is developed in WordPress and its Robots.txt is below.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

------------------------updated ------------------

this is sitemap
http://aulipackages.com/page-sitemap.xml

How to index inner pages?

Comment: The warning says that you have wp-admin URLs in your sitemap. Not sure why you want to index *more* pages when the problem is that you're trying to index *too many* pages.

Comment: Please review once more the question I have updated the sitemap there. There is no wp-admin page in sitemap. Should I submit the single url in to Google?